# How to use a new key pair downloaded from Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keychain, pem, key-pair

Attempting to download a new Key Pair as I am about to Launch a new Amazon EC2 Instance. When I click to download, here is what I am seeing in Keychain Access:

`An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.`

Unsuccessful solution attempts include:

1. Running `security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` in **terminal**
2. Clicking to *Lock* and then *Unlock* **Login** in **Keychain Accesss**
3. `rm ida_rsa.pub`, `rm ida_rsa`, and all other old `.pem`'s in **~/.ssh**

Comment: This is how I used to import keys into keychains, before I switched to linux: `ssh-add -K foo.pem`

Comment: Where are you clicking "Download" -- in the EC2 console, or on what appears to be a Mac? When you say "download from EC2", do you mean an EC2 instance, or the EC2 console? What do you mean by "new key pair" -- where and how are you generating this "new" key pair? Can you please edit your question and be very explicit in _where_ you are performing these steps?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein upon launching a new EC2 Instance, I am selecting the option to create a new key pair. I begin by naming that key pair and then clicking "Download Key Pair" on the Amazon screen... The download itself is working. But when clicking on the download on my Mac to open the .pem file, I am seeing the "An error has occurred. Unable to import an item." in my Mac's Keychain Access

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are experiencing a problem when opening the `.pem` file that was downloaded to your computer.

This is because a `.pem` file is not intended to be run. Rather, it is used by an `ssh` command to access the instance. For example:

```
ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```

The `ssh` command *uses* the keypair, but the keypair itself is just a data file and is not intended to be 'opened'.

Some alternatives to using `ssh` and keypairs are:

- [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html), which uses an agent installed on the machine to establish a connection
- [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html), which establishes an ssh connection via web browser without needing a keypair